# How to control a callback?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use case : I have a topic which is subscribed by a ROS node locally and also by a ROs node on a remote system ,Since both the nodes are subscribed to the topic, both node gets a a call back when the message is published , But i want the callback on the remote system to work only during some times otherwise it is done locally .

I could always recieve the payload via the callback on the remote system and decide not to do any computation with it . But the problem is I am  loading the bandwidth with information i dont use ,i want to prevent this ?

Is there any way to achieve this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307894/how-to-control-a-callback-?/) by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-08**:
A general comment: you now have 5 questions posted of which 3 received a answers. It would be good if you could go back to those questions and see which of the answers actually solved your problem. Then *accept* those answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But i want the callback on the remote system to work only during some times otherwise it is done locally

I don't believe that is how publish-subscribe works -- or at least, not in the default implementation in ROS 1.

At the user/application level, there is no knowledge/state your publisher has access to that would allow it to actively influence which subscribers receive messages, neither whether they have actual callbacks registered for those messages.

In addition: publish-subscribe (again: as implemented in ROS 1) provides location transparency: nodes do not "know" where other nodes are (or where they are deployed).

So "*the callback on the remote system*" is not something that you can say given these two properties.

But this is all at the user/application level, the middleware obviously *does know* where other nodes are (see also #q203129).

---

A naive way to do what you describe could be to deregister your subscribers whenever they are not needed. Then resubscribe again when the need is there. Provided you're not doing that multiple times per second that should not incur too much latency / performance overhead.

*Perhaps* this is a use-case for [ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html).

Alternatively: if control over where (and *when*) processing takes place is important, it could be that services or actions are a more suitable interaction pattern.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1